# Core Data Stack code don't want to put in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

Is there any way to use `Core Data` without putting Core data stack code in `AppDelegate`?

Comment: You can create the managed context anywhere you like. The idea behind putting it in the app delegate is that it is a singleton so it is easy to get the managed context from anywhere in your app, but there is nothing "magic" about the app delegate

Comment: Put the core data stack in a singleton class and reference the context from there. But what are you trying to achieve by not putting it in the app delegate?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to put it in the app delegate. You can just import CoreData in any class file etc and use it from there. As the comment above mentions the managed context can be accessed from anywhere. Take a look at this :

http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-1/